# No statistics shown at DSpace home

Tags: solr, statistics, dspace

I would like to see statistics for our DSpace instance. But if I click the statistics link (in the DSpace demo it's: http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/statistics)
I see:

No reports currently available  
There are currently no reports available for this service. Please check back later.

In Solr, Usage Statistics, Search Statistics and Workflow Statistics everything is fine. 
So I checked the code and found that for the statistics page the class org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.artifactbrowser.StatisticsViewer is used. 
This uses the old statistics implementation (where text files need to be generated and parsed).

Is this the expected behaviour and why is it working at http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/statistics ? 
 
I think to make this work we would have to run the legacy scripts stat-general, stat-initial, stat-monthly ... from (https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Command+Line+Operations)

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. The /statistics link directs to the old legacy statistics.

On DSpace Demo they do seem to be generated now when I accessed
http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/statistics

Using the legacy statistics is not advised since they are not subject to the modern robot detection and filtering principles that are used in the more recent SOLR statistics implementation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. In this case It is not a bug in our system.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to run few commands on C:\dspace\bin

**1. dspace report-general and 
2. dspace report-monthly** 
A report folder will be created in C:\dspace\reports folder.

copy the report folder and paste in tomcat webapps.. jspui.. restart tomcat and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended use the follow commands

```
cd {dspace-DIR}/bin/
./dspace index-discovery -b
./dspace stat-initial
./dspace stat-report-initial
./dspace stat-general
./dspace stat-monthly
./dspace stat-report-monthly
./dspace stat-report-general
```